# How to check whether element exsits or not in a List[Any] using Scala

Tags: list, scala, contains

I have a list like the following:

```
val map_temp =
  List(
    (List("SRC_123","SRC_999"),"TRGT_123"),
    (List("SRC_456"),"TRGT_456"),
    (List("SRC_789"),"TRGT_789"),
    (List("SRC_888"),"TRGT_888"),
  )
```

I want to check whether `SRC_999` exists in it.

I tried the following:

```
map_temp.foreach {
  case(key, value) =>
    if (key.contains("SRC_999")) {
      print("yes exists")
    }
}
```

This causes the following error

```
error: value contains is not a member of Any
case(key:Any, value) => if(key.contains("SRC_99"))
```

I have also tried this:

```
map_temp.foreach(a => if(a._1.contains("SRC_999")))
```

But this causes the following error:

```
error: value contains is not a member of Any
mapped.foreach(a => print(a._1.contains("SRC_999")))
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this?

By not having a `List[Any]`.

By having a `List[Any]`, you are explicitly telling Scala that the elements could be *anything*. That means Scala doesn't know anything about the elements. It doesn't even know whether they have a `contains` method or not. The elements could be integers, for example, which don't have a `contains` method.

Comment: I tried this also map_temp.map(_.asInstanceOf[(String, String)]).

Comment: map_temp.foreach(a => if (a._1.contains("SRC_999")){print("yes Exits" )}) results:                         java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
val map_temp =
  List(
    (List("SRC_123","SRC_999"),"TRGT_123"),
    (List("SRC_456"),"TRGT_456"),
    (List("SRC_789"),"TRGT_789"),
    (List("SRC_888"),"TRGT_888"),
  )

def exists[A](input: List[(List[A], _)], what: A): Boolean =
  input.exists(_._1.contains(what))

// should be found
assert(exists(map_temp, "SRC_999"))
assert(exists(map_temp, "SRC_888"))

// should not be found
assert(!exists(map_temp, "SRC_998"))
assert(!exists(map_temp, "TRGT_123"))
```

I don't think you actually have a `List[Any]` to begin with. It appears that you are experiencing a couple of type errors that could mislead you into believing so. Your `map_temp` is a `List[(List[String], String)]`.

If that's not the case and you are getting `map_temp` from a method that for some reason returns a `List[Any]`, if you're in control of that method you can change it to reflect the actual type. If you can't, even though it's not safe, you can attempt to cast it.

With few changes, you can also retrieve items:

```
def find[A, B](input: List[(List[A], B)], what: A): Option[B] =
  input.find(_._1.contains(what)).map(_._2)

// should be found
assert(find(map_temp, "SRC_999") == Some("TRGT_123"))
assert(find(map_temp, "SRC_888") == Some("TRGT_888"))

// should not be found
assert(find(map_temp, "SRC_998") == None)
assert(find(map_temp, "TRGT_123") == None)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/XGsqz5GbQoOexjBFDavAYg/11).

Comment: Hi stefanobaghino,

Comment: I was getting as List[Any] since as below.
 var r = List.range(0,inst.charMapping.length)

var srcChars1 = r.map{i => if(1==1) inst.charMapping(i).srcChars.get else I}

var tgtChar1 = r.map{i => if(1==1) inst.charMapping(i).tgtChar.get else i}

map_temp = srcChars1 zip tgtChar1

Comment: How to get it as List[(List[String], String)]?

Comment: So, I assume that the `1==1` in `if` conditions are placeholders for something else, since they will of course always evaluate to `true`. If you can remove them, I would recommend doing so. If you can't, consider that the type returned by an `if` expression must be a super type of the two branches. e.g the type of `if (true) 4 else "4"` is the closest common super type to `4` of type `Int`, and `"4"` of type `String`, which happens to be `Any`. Either drop the `if` or make sure that both branches return a `List[String]` for `srcChars1` and a `String` for `tgtChar1`.

Comment: For the function you wrote, is there a way to get the only string value from List[(List[String], String)] if SRC_999 exits

Comment: Do you mean something with a signature like `def find[A, B](input: List[(List[A], B)], what: A): Option[B]`, where in your case both `A`s and `B`s are `String`s? If that's the case, I've updated my answer (notice I used the old name `find` for the new method and I renamed `find` to `exists`. Those names better match what's going on, as you can tell from the standard library methods I'm using.

Comment: I request you to suggest a method project output as B instead of some(B)

Comment: I tried passing the output of the code part you wrote to the below function.
def show(x: Option[String]) = x match {
      case Some(s) => s
      case None => "?"
   }
Its working. But still is there anyway to get firstoutput itself as B instead of some(B)

Comment: I would not recommend it, as you have to express that that method can end up not finding the item you're looking for. If you're ok with having `null`s in your codebase you can use `orNull`. If you prefer having a default value you can use `getOrElse`.

Comment: So, was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The `map_temp` value is `List[(List[String], String)]`, not `List[Any]`. You can check for the element you are looking for like this:

```
map_temp.exists(_._1.contains("SRC_999"))
```